# Git submodule suddenly no longer recognized as valid repo, some files in .git/modules/[submodule] missing

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've been having a similar issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747382/existing-git-repo-no-longer-recognized-as-a-valid-repository), and it likewise seems to have appeared suddenly; however, for me it seems to happen due to a submodule - the error I'm getting on running `git status` in the main project is

```
fatal: not a git repository: [submodule]/../.git/modules/[submodule]
```

When I tried to check whether something had happened to the paths in `[submodule]/.git` or `.git/modules/[submodule]/config` as suggested in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893585/15704972), I found that the latter didn't exist, and more was missing. Specifically, for me the only contents of `.git/modules/[submodule]` are the `refs` and `objects` dirs and `packed-refs`.

I've tried to add a HEAD as suggested in [a comment on the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747382/existing-git-repo-no-longer-recognized-as-a-valid-repository#comment88503270_50747382) but can't quite work out what to put as `ref` - a simple `refs/heads/foo` (where `heads/foo` exists in the `refs` dir in `.git/modules/[submodule]`, I checked that much) fails with

```
fatal: bad object HEAD
fatal: 'git status --porcelain=2' failed in submodule
```

and trying to point it at `[submodule]../.git/modules/[submodule]/refs/heads/foo` only gives me the original error. Can I get back to a usable submodule, and if so, how? For the submodule, there fortunately is a remote repo with all the changes, ditto for *most* of the main project (I was in the middle of trying out something I hadn't tracked just yet, so would prefer not having to nuke it...).

Comment: You can remove the submodule completely and re-clone it (just move the existing one out of the way, saving whatever you have just in case you want it back later). It's probably a good idea to figure out what clobbered it though, to avoid having it happen again.

Comment: @torek - I would suspect a fumbled accidental `rm` back when I set up the submodule (I messed up the order of adding it and running `git-filter-repo` on the main project several times...) that I thought I'd stopped in time, except that it evidently *was* working for a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it (after [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69466210/git-submodule-suddenly-no-longer-recognized-as-valid-repo-some-files-in-git-mo#comment122795615_69466210) from @torek):

I first deleted the submodule by manually carrying out the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule/36593218#36593218) (to avoid git potentially choking on the no-longer-a-repo subdirectory): manually deleting the `[submodule]` sections from `.git/config`, and removing `.git/modules/[submodule]` as well as the dir with the submodule. At this point, the main project behaved like
a repo again, so I could stage that last change (with `git add [submodule]`) to get the submodule out of the index.
After that, I could re-add the submodule with `git submodule add [url/to/submodule]`.